# How to get notify when user has enabled Location services

Tags: android

I have an application that sends push. Push sends request to enable Location services.
As soon as I receive push, I have called a notification, and on notification action

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(viewIntent);
```

But how to log, if the user has enabled location settings or not.

Push is received in `broadcastReceiver`, So we dont have `startActivityForResult()`. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: use  locationManager.isProviderEnabled(String provider) pass the parameter as LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you :

```
 private boolean isLocationEnabled()
  {
   LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
   return service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)||service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

Add this permissions to manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Its not getting result from user action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    LocationManager lm = null;
         boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
            if(lm==null)
                lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            try{
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
            try{
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }catch(Exception ex){}

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){

    ///////////// do you dialog show code here

 ////////////call the intent to open location service setting

     Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS );
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

**Also add this permission to menifest file.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I want to send back result to server that, user has processed the request send by push. As soon as the user enables the setting.

Comment: if the if condition will not execute then the service is enabled. so you can send update by writing else part